# How to Display Percentage values on TOP of CCC Bar Chart in CDE (Non-Stacked Bar Chart)

Tags: bar-chart, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools, ccc

My requirement is to show percentage values on the top of the bar ccc Bar chart (non-stacked), so far I have got the percentages in between the bar charts all I need is to display them on the top.

I have added this function in clickable action and made clickable TRUE

function(scene) { var pctVar = scene.vars.value.percent;

alert(pctVar.label);

}

Then in advance properties I have changed values visible = True and Valuemask= {Value}% so until this I can get values in middle of the bar chart

So what and all I need to do to show the percentages on the TOP of the Bar Charts? Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'on the TOP'? You mean *inside* the bars? Like having the numbers rendered over the yellow and green bar's background? If so, you will also probably change the size or rotation of the numbers.

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz As you can see in picture percentages should be on top of the bars, when I was doing this with non-stacked bars percentages came in between the value bars. All I want is to display the % value as shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

valuesAnchor: Top

Extension points [

label_textMargin: 1
label_textBaseline: bottom
}

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation how this answers the question and how/why it works.